# How to get updated object from Mongo

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I have a Match document that have ReferenceMany(Scores) on it.
When I add a new Score to a Match, and return the Match, the new score isn't there. On the next request though, the score is there. How can I force Doctrine to update my Match in the same request?

Code:

```
$match = $dm->getRepository('Match')->find($matchId);
// Save score.
$dm->persist($score);

// Add score to match
$match->addScores($score);

$dm->flush(); // <-- This doesn't help.

return $match; // <-- Is missing the new Score.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions to my problem:

1. doing a redirect to a GET match, instead of returning in the same request. It works, but it felt a bit awkward.
2. Do `$dm->createQueryBuilder('Match') ->field('_id')->equals($id) ->refresh(TRUE) ->getQuery() ->execute();` at the end to get a refreshed Match from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `$dm->flush();` after `$dm->persist($score);` ?

Comment: try with the flush after $dm->persist($score); and BEFORE $match->addScores($score);

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter how many times I call flush(), or where I put the calls. I might need to refactor this method a bit..